# CipherOutputStream used with rsa

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption

i'm ruining a very simple RSA encryption in java. but the output file seems to be empty.
the same thing works if i try it without a CipherOutputStream. i can see each write
cycle in the loop has no effect.
any clue ... 
thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;


public class ExampleRSA {
    private static String VIDEO_SOURCE_FILE = "C:/Users/ggoldman/Desktop/Video/inputVideo.dv";
    private static String EncryptedFile = "C:/Users/ggoldman/Desktop/Video/encVideo.dv";
    private static File decfile = new File("C:/Users/ggoldman/Desktop/Video/decVideo.dv");
    private static File incfile = new File(EncryptedFile);
    private static File sourceMedia = new File(VIDEO_SOURCE_FILE);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        // Encrypt

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceMedia);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(incfile);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

        byte[] block = new byte[32];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            cos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
        cos.close();
}
```

Comment: Works for me with txt files.Check your path and Files permission

Comment: @Yahor10, behaviour reproduced on my machine. It seems to depend on input somehow.

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221730/my-cipheroutputstream-fails-silently

Comment: One more discussion here http://www.coderanch.com/t/134562/Security/CipherOutputStream-not-outputing

Comment: looking at the discussions suggested here i guess it's not meant to work on large files but i still need to get a benchmark for the time it takes to compere.

Comment: "*i'm **ruining** a very simple RSA encryption*" ... don't be so hard on yourself ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that the program has finished when you detect an empty file? RSA over a video file can take ages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't encrypt and decrypt whole files with just RSA (at least not if they have more then just a small string).  The RSA algorithm can only encrypt a single block, and 
it is rather slow for doing a whole file.

You can encrypt the file using 3DES or AES, and then encrypt the AES key 
using intended recipient's RSA public key.